# Long string in VS editor

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, edit

I have a very long hardcoded string in visual studio, C#
How can I split it in editor into several lines?

I need it in order that code reading will be more simple

Answer (score 3):

You can use +, at compile time they will be concatenated into one string.

```
string longString = "Hello " +
"world!";
```

Answer (score 3):

use `@` [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) and you can spread it over multiple lines.

```
string multiLinestring = @"Some Long string
                            Over mutliple lines
                            .....
                            ........";
```

The above string will tread the indentation as spaces in the string. If you want a single space between multiple lines then:

```
 string multiLinestring = @"Some Long string
 Over mutliple lines
 .....
 ........";
```

This would return: `Some Long string\r\n Over mutliple lines\r\n .....\r\n ........"`

Comment: What if it is long line without new lines?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov, then string concatenation has to be used, string verbatim would not be useful.

Comment: _"Very long hardcoded string"_ sounds as if it is a single `string` which does not (necessarily) contain line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in resource, and let the VS take care of it.